# Uniform circular array (UCA) beamforming using FFT

Tags: antenna, signal-processing, fft, radar, beamforming

As far as I know, conventional beamforming using FFT can return a range-angle map. However, this only works with a uniform linear array (ULA).

I'm wondering if the same approach works for UCA. I guess we need to modify the algorithm a bit, but the documents out there are quite limited. Have you ever tried it? Can give me some suggestions?

Comment: It appears to have been done many times before. https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=beamforming+using+FFT+circular&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart